# Polymer Paper-Button created in JavaScript click event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, events, polymer, paper-elements

I'm having trouble with my polymer paper-button which I create in my JavaScript code and assign to a div in my HTML. I've been Googling for a while but am coming up empty handed. I simple want to be able to do something when it is clicked but i can't figure out how to assign it's click property a function.

Thanks in advance.

```
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    var mainCollapse = document.getElementById('collapse');

    /*--------------Contact Details Collapseable--------------*/
    var contactDetailsDiv = document.getElementById('contactDetails');
    var gitBtn = document.createElement('paper-button');
    gitBtn.textContent = 'GitHub Profile.';
    gitBtn.raised = true;
    gitBtn.id = 'gitButton';
    gitBtn.link = 'https://github.com/SKHolmes';
    gitBtn.onClick = function(){
      console.log('here');    }

    var githubDiv = document.getElementById('githubDiv');
    githubDiv.appendChild(gitBtn);   

    app.displayContactDetails = function(){
      var contactDetails = contactDetailsDiv.innerHTML;
      mainCollapse.innerHTML = contactDetails;
    }

    //Button Listeners
    document.getElementById("contact-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
      app.displayContactDetails();    
      mainCollapse.toggle();      
    });

    document.getElementById('gitButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log('here');
    });
  });  
})(document);
```

Okay it's getting a little ridiculous now I've tried nearly everything to get this button to print something to the console. Including all of these.

```
app.listen(gitBtn, 'tap', 'test');

app.listen(gitBtn, 'click', 'test');

gitBtn.addEventListener('tap', function(){
  alert('here');
});

gitBtn.onclick = 'test';

gitBtn.click = function(){ console.log('here'); }   

app.test = function(){
  console.log('here');
}
gitBtn.setAttribute('on-click', 'app.test');
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you adding the `paper-button` with JS instead of declaring it in your HTML?

Comment: Because whenever I add it to my HTML it causes problems with the iron-collapse that contains it, the collapse does the opening animation then doesn't open to be specific, it's weird. I narrowed the bug down to my paper-button. So I took it out of the HTML and am adding it to a div imperatively. It renders and animates as it should do when I do it this way

Comment: Have you tried using `gitBtn.onclick = function() ...`?

Comment: Yes unfortunately nothing. I just retried it to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#imperative-listeners) describe how to imperatively add event listeners:

> Use automatic node finding and the convenience methods `listen` and
>   `unlisten`.
>
> ```
> this.listen(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
>
> this.unlisten(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
> ```
>
> The listener callbacks are invoked with `this` set to the element instance.
>
> If you add a listener imperatively, you need to remove it
>   imperatively. This is commonly done in the `attached` and `detached`
>   callbacks. If you use the listeners object or annotated event
>   listeners, Polymer automatically adds and removes the event listeners.

So, you would bind your `onClick` function like this:

```
gitBtn.attached = function() {
  this.listen(this, 'tap', 'onClick');
};
gitBtn.detached = function() {
  this.unlisten(this, 'tap', 'onClick');
};
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/ripaxolosu/1/edit?html,console,output)

```js
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    var gitBtn = document.createElement('paper-button');
    gitBtn.textContent = 'GitHub Profile.';
    gitBtn.raised = true;
    gitBtn.id = 'gitButton';
    gitBtn.link = 'https://github.com/SKHolmes';
    gitBtn.onClick = function() {
      console.log('gitBtn.onClick()');
      log.innerHTML += 'gitBtn.onClick()<br>';
    };

    gitBtn.attached = function() {
      this.listen(this, 'tap', 'onClick');
    };
    gitBtn.detached = function() {
      this.unlisten(this, 'tap', 'onClick');
    };

    var githubDiv = document.getElementById('githubDiv');
    githubDiv.appendChild(gitBtn);

  });

})(document);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="githubDiv"></div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</body>

</html>
```